# TypesScript Decorators in IONIC

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using decorators to show loaders when I make any http request,  but I'm facing 2 problems

1 - When I use the decorator de Http Request is not being called;

2 - How to inform the decorator that my request has finished and then, dismiss de loader;

```
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

export function loader(mensagem: string, tempo: number = 20000) {
    return function (target, key, descriptor) {
        var originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function (...args) {
            createLoader(mensagem, tempo);
        };
        return descriptor;
    };
}

async function createLoader(mensagem: string, duracao?: number) {
    let loading: LoadingController = new LoadingController();
    const loader = await loading.create({
        message: mensagem,
        spinner: 'crescent',
        duration: duracao || 20000
    });
    return await loader.present();
}
```

My Subscription:

```
  @loader('Searching', 10)// Decorator that should dismiss when http request finish
  async getEndereco() {// Nothing happends here, even a console.log()
    this.eventsService.getAddress(Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('event')))//request
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe((address: CustumerAddress) => {            
        this.form.get('select').patchValue({
          address: address.address
          description: address.description
    }); 
  },
    e => {
      this.utils.showError(e);
    });
```

}

Comment: Hey! Quick thing... that function `getEndereco()` is a bit confusing... I think you want to get an address as `string` correct? But you're expecting a **Number** from the `snapshot`? What's the 'event' supposed to return? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do here? There might be an easier and simple way around it.

Comment: I'm using the Number() constructior to transform de url parameter do number. But I think it works passing it as string, does not matter. When I remove de decorator it works normally...

Comment: Why are you using function keyword!!! You could just async createLoader(...) , return (target,key,descriptor)=>{....} , when you write function keyword it will we javascript and thus the typescript code at some parts could be affected with it.